# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: instagram bot

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I am creating a bot to unfollow people on Instagram.

It was working fine but as I used it I got an error.

When I go in the page of the user that i want to unfollow i got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
```

This error is thrown because my selenium can not find the button unfollow the user.

**My code:**

```py
try:
 self._make_driver_wait("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/button")
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/button").click()
 self._make_driver_wait("//button[contains(text(), 'unfollow')]")
 self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'unfollow')]").click()
 except :
  print("time out")
```

I don't know why it can't find the element after a period of time.

I did inspect the button and the XPath of the page was the same as in my code when I click it I could unfollow.

Does Instagram have some sort of protection? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I make it work with this :

> ```
>            self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("_6VtSN").click()
> ```

i remplace the absolute path with a find to class and it work like a baby :D

thanks for all